# Tab completion in adb shell

Tags: android

The only thing I found is [to cross compile bash](http://www.kbrandt.com/2009/06/how-to-cross-compile-the-bash-shell-for-android-15.html). Is there another way to have tab completion in the Android shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a director answer but someone posted a pre-compiled binary of bash using those instructions of mine [here](http://android.modaco.com/content/software/301932/bash-4-1-native-app-for-android/).

Answer (score 4):

If you install busybox, it has ash; which also has the tab completion thing, plus command-line history with Dpad-Up

Answer (score 0):

[MirBSD korn shell](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) is working on android and supports tab completion.

Answer (score -1):

new adb after Sun, 1 Mar 2015 15:06:21 -0800 fix the issue.
the android source code in system/core/, the commit id:50184062b87a121458fff7d8bda6656c59c71c77